# Look through channel's message history in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord

Given a specific channel's id, I want to look at all of the messages sent to check if it contains a string of text using the rewrite of discord.py.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
token = "example token"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of using `channel.history`, depending on where you use the command, will search for all messages from that user for the past 100 messages, hopes this helps. Feel free to change this to how you want, it will only currently look for the messages sent by the author of the command.

```
@client.command()
async def history(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    counter = 0
    async for message in ctx.channel.history(limit = 100):
        if message.author == member:
            counter += 1

    await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} has sent {counter} messages in this {ctx.channel.mention}')
```